SCIP-SDP for solving mixed integer semidefinite programs
I have been looking at SCIP, specifically SCIP-SDP for solving a mixed semidefinite program - however I can't seem to find any examples on how I implement it in Python with PySCIPOpt.
Does anyone know where I can find any examples? I have been looking through the documentation, but they do not specify the syntax.

I don't think it's supported. This was made clear in 2019 and a simple SDP search doesn't show any code too.

Danke schön :-)
